# Integrate backbone.js collections with Datatables

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I am creating a single page application using backbone.js. That page will contain a table list of products and I should be able to perfom sorting on the columns and multi row select functionality. I wanted to know if there was a sample that shows how to  feed in data to datatables from a backbone collection. So that using datatable functionality I can perform sort and multi row selects.

Comment: Though datatables is a good plugin, I think you can deploy your interactive table easily with backbone alone.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Datatables has a very well defined API which means it should be a trivial exercise to generate output from a Backbone collection that can be fed into the API.  Have a look at the `toJSON` method on the `Collection` and `Model` object in the Backbone source.  It should give you some ideas.